# Some errors occured while accessing svn working copy database on Android Studio?

Tags: android, svn

Hi I linked my project to svn but it throws an error like :

Some errors occurred while accessing svn working copy database.

How can I solve it?

Build: 1.4, AI-141.2288178, 20150928,

1.8.0_60-b27x64 Oracle Corporation, Linux(amd64) v3.16.0-51-generic unknown (1366x768)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently had a similar problem. In our case, our machine had a non-english ubuntu system. Reinstalling Ubuntu with English, fixed the problem.

Comment: I changed my language to English. It works . Thanks :)